# How to lock drawer menu only on some screens of my stack?

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer, stack-navigator

What I need to do is just block the swipe action to open the menu on a specific screen of my stack

Stack:

```
const SignedInStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name='Confluence' component={Confluence} />
    <Stack.Screen name='QRCode' component={Main} />
    <Stack.Screen name='Notifications' component={Notifications} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

DrawerMenu:

```
const DrawerMenu = () => (
  <Drawer.Navigator
    screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
  >
    <Drawer.Screen
      name="SignedInStack"
      component={SignedInStack}
    />
  <Drawer.Navigator/>
);
```

App.js:

```
const App = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <DrawerMenu />
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using "swipeEnabled"?

```
options={{ swipeEnabled: false }}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/

Comment: This really works but I can only put it in the drawer navigator which only has my stack, it makes all screens swipe disabled :/

Comment: you can use it to a specific screen

Comment: Just in screens inside the drawer menu, on the stack this option doesn't work